# Getting unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input Syntax Error - can't find issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting a `unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input` syntax error for my UsersController class, but can't for the life of me figure out what here is spelled wrong/why `end` is throwing it off.

```
Class UsersController < ApplicationController
   before_action :authenticate_user!

   def update
     if current_user.update_attributes(user_params)
       flash[:notice] = "User information updated"
       redirect_to edit_user_registration_path
     else
       flash[:error] = "Invalid user information"
       redirect_to edit_user_registration_path
     end
   end

   private

   def user_params
     params.require(:user).permit(:name, :avatar)
   end
end
```

Comment: Indent by 4 spaces for syntax highlighting (or select and command-K)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining the class, the keyword "class" should be of lowercase, not uppercase, so try changing:

```
Class UsersController < ApplicationController
```

to

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
```

Hope that helps!